# Matching ONLY Numbers / Persian Characters And Latin

Tags: php, regex

i need a regex code that matches Numbers/Persian Characters And Latin ( A-Z )

i wrote the following code

`preg_match("/[A-Za-z\s\x{0600}-\x{06FF}0-9_\.\- ]/u",$_POST['input'] )`

and works fine .

but there is a problem, i dont want to input have any ( @,#,!,%,$,&,* ) characters .

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an `negative lookahead` assertion in your regex to check that there is no such character. Place this at the beginning of your regex. I mean just after the `/`.

```
(?!.*[(@#!%$&*)])
```

For example:

```
preg_match("/^(?!.*[(@#!%$&*)])[A-Za-z\s\x{0600}-\x{06FF}0-9_\.\- ]+$/u",$_POST['input'] )
```

Comment: still does not working. im entering ` تست@!#Test123 ` in my input , and preg_match returns true

Comment: @user2077916 I thought you are matching with only one character! Please check my updated regex. I assume your `\x{0600}-\x{06FF}` is correct.