# Data Input Mask For Specific Language Latter Allow? Like persian latter?

Tags: php, html, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

Please help me to set Input Mask For Persian Latter.
It allows Vehicle License Number in English but I need to set allow when its Persian language.

```
<input data-tooltip='Vehicle License Plate Number' id="veh_lic_no" data-inputmask="'mask': '(99) 99A999'" minlength="7" name="veh_lic_no" type="text" class="validate tooltipped" value="" required> 
 <label for="veh_lic_no" ><?php print _t('12', 'Vehicle License Plate') ?></label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching ONLY Numbers / Persian Characters And Latin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880977/matching-only-numbers-persian-characters-and-latin)

Comment: but data-inputmask="'mask': '(99) 99A999'" here A i would like to allow persian character any suggestion?